# Renting a laptop for personal use in Las Vegas?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, rental, las-vegas

I need to stay in Las Vegas for a month, but I won't be able to take a personal laptop with me.

I will be attending a trade conference, so I will be flying with a company laptop and tablet device. Because of this I am not sure if I will be able to take my personal laptop with me as well.

Is there any personal-use laptop rental service available in Las Vegas? Googling for "rent a computer in Las Vegas" seems to show mostly ads of laptop rentals that lease computers for presentations to companies. Is there any similar reasonably priced service for personal laptop rentals? The laptop does not need to be high-end, it will mostly be used for internet browsing, Skype and occasionally writing documents.

Alternatively, would it be possible to go through the airport carrying two laptops? (I do not intend to take my personal laptop with me unless I can take it hassle free).

Comment: Regarding taking multiple laptops: You would not have any problems taking two laptops. Just make sure to present both of them in the TSA checkpoint and put them in a bin separate from your normal items. I have taken 3 laptops in the past and did not have any problems, other than the occasional weird look. Safe travels!

Comment: It would seem strange but shouldn't be a problem. I hade once three smartphones, two Kindles and one laptop. "Is it all yours?" - "Yes!" And the security check continued.

Comment: I have frequently been flying with a personal laptop and a company laptop without issues. Those flights have mostly been within Europe but also several times between Europe and US. I have rarely even been asked why I was travelling with two laptops. All it meant was that I was slowed down ever so slightly at the security check because I had to use an extra tray and those trays end up quite far apart on the other side of the security check.

Comment: I also travel internationally with multiple laptops, phone, tablet and iPod.  I have never been asked about them.  But I pay for it with sore shoulders from humping all that stuff around.

Comment: I travel 30+ times a year with two laptops. No issues ever.

Comment: Any reason why you cannot / do not want to use the work laptop for your personal stuff? If it's company policy only, I would definitely ask if they could make an exception for this month-long business travel..

Comment: The DefCon hacker conference is held in Las Vegas. If there was a service that let you hold onto a laptop for a week and then gave it to someone else it would be used to attack the next customer. Even with wiping the computer  there are ways to modify the BIOS for instance. I can't seeing a service like that staying in business while renting computers for less than a cheap new laptop would cost.

Answer (score 8):

I have travelled with both my work and personal laptops; I'm not sure why you think that will not be possible for you. (I think my biggest tech load was two laptops, two phones, one or two tablets, a cell signal booster, and a slew of external batteries and chargers.  Went through security with the laptops and tablets flat in bins and everything else pulled out in clear packing cubes.  Zero hassles.)

If you have some compelling reason to leave your personal laptop at home (perhaps it is used by other family members, perhaps it contains data you would not wish to be in reach of US laws) then, for a month of travel, it will almost certainly be cheaper to buy a new laptop in Vegas, and at the end of the month either sell it or just bring it home, than to rent one for a month. (Source: worked on a project where management rented machines for "temporary" staff.  Turned out to be a rather expensive mistake.)

A quick search online found Chromebooks for under $70, and low end laptops for just over a hundred dollars; I can't imagine anything you could rent for a month cheaper than that.

Comment: There may be customs issues traveling internationally with multiple laptops, although usually nothing insurmountable (e.g. if you have proper receipts/proof of ownership etc and can demonstrate you're not planning to sell them), and most Western countries will be used to it.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any personal-use laptop rental service available in Las Vegas?

You're unlikely to find a place to rent a laptop anywhere in the city, as that's not something most people are interested in. However it shouldn't be to hard too get a used laptop [from the local Craigslist](https://lasvegas.craigslist.org/search/sys?query=laptop). Prices start from $100, depending on condition.

> Alternatively, would it be possible to go through the airport carrying two laptops?

You can even carry five laptops at a time. There's no law that says "one laptop per person at most", people routinely carry lots of electronics without an issue.